# How to recover statement of md-input in Angular-material

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" >
   <label>username</label>
     <input type="text" name="username" ng-model="user.username" required md-no-asterisk>
     <div ng-messages="loginForm.username.$error">
       <div ng-message="required">It is required.</div>
     </div>
</md-input-container>
<md-button class="md-raised" id="clean">clean</md-button>
```

I want to recover the statement of md-input via a button, so I do the following work.

```
angular
    .module('xxx', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])
    .directive('xxx', function(){
        return{
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'js/app/user/login-form.html',
            link: link
        };
        function link(scope, element, attr) {
        element.find('#clean').on('click', function(){
            element.find('input').val('');
            scope.user.username = '';
        });
    }
});
```

The result is not good because it is not the original statement which the font is gray on the input line. How to solve it out?

After loading:

[image]

After clicking the button

[image]